# AJAX Request to Method Contained in Class File

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to make an AJAX request on a Razor Page, calling a method contained in separate class file (NOT in the pagemodel for the page - as I eventually want to make the same request from multiple different pages).

Unfortunately, the request fails. I think it may have to do with the syntax I've used, or perhaps the class I'm trying to call being of the wrong type. Note that the request DOES work if I change the url to a method in the pagemodel (no other changes required).

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, and AJAX requests, so if there's a fundamental misunderstanding here, let me know.

AJAX Request Code (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Tools/Redirect?handler=AccessRedirect',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Request Success, Data = " + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Request Failed");
        }
    });
})
```

(I've also tried `url: /Tools/Redirect/AccessRedirect` using a method simply called `AccessRedirect`, with the `[HttpGet]` attribute, but that didn't work either)

C# Class Code (File is Redirect.cs in folder Tools):

```
    public class Redirect
    {
        public JsonResult OnGetAccessRedirect()
        {
            return new JsonResult("test");
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. your `Redirect` must derive from `Controller` and must have suffix like `RedirectController` ... 2. What is your route ?

Comment: Is that `JsonResult` exists outside page's `.cshtml.cs` file? I don't think you can place the JsonResult outside the page code file, why not just create static class with static methods and return `JsonResult` using that method? Note: Razor pages must derive from `PageModel` instead of `Controller`.

Comment: Are you adding the Anti Forgery request token? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental misunderstanding is that Razor Pages requests must target a handler method in a `PageModel` class. You can't map URLs to arbitrary methods in class files. Handler methods must be in a class that derives from `PageModel`, and they must follow certain conventions.

You can read more about handler methods in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

If you have code that you want to centralise, you can put that in a C# class, and then call the method in your handler method

Comment: Thanks for the advice - that makes sense.