# Making an AJAX request to a controller or page model with Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

With the addition of Razor Pages as an option for .net core I am a bit confused. I am aware that handlers can be used to call multiple actions of the same HTTP type. But what if I want to create an action that will be used across multiple pages.

I am assuming simply creating a controller without a view is the way to go for these actions. I just want to make sure I will be able to call the actions from a razor page w/ jQuery AJAX or a regular button/anchor tag.

I would like the best of both worlds to be available. Should I use the razor pages template and add controllers or use the mvc template and add pages. Or does it not matter.

Comment: No problem to call an action through AJAX. With button/anchor could be a problem. It depends on the data you return. If you return a PDF file, browser will open it, but if you return `View` you'll get an error.

Comment: Both approaches work and it's mostly a matter of opinion, but it would be sensible to use a combination of MVC and Razor Pages for this.

Comment: Hi @Blake Rivell , did you ever find a solution for this as it's a problem I have recently solved?

Answer (score 1):

I use an API controller for AJAX actions and Razor Pages for the basic GET/POST. If you want to make an AJAX call back to a Razor Page (or even a controller) see the post below about adding the AntiForgery Token to the call.

[Example AJAX call back to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page)