# What AJAX url should I use to run my delete action in my Razor page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm newbie to AJAX calls and I need to perform simple CRUD operations using AJAX call to  Razor Pages. I made a simple function that should delete a row in the table, but it is not working no matter what I try.

Every time I execute the code I get the error message. For first row in the table the error message is:

> Error something went wrong with id = 1url:
>   /Person/Index?handler=DeleteById&id=1

As you can see in commented javascript I tried to use several urls, but none of them worked and I'm getting the same error.

I believe this should be easy, but I'm missing something. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

My Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication20.Pages.Person.IndexModel
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div id="msg"></div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].PersonName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].PersonAddress)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Person)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteId('@item.PersonId');">Delete</button>


                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript (embed in `<script>` tag at bottom of page)

```
    function DeleteId(id) {
        var options = {};
        //options.url = "/Person/Index?id=" + id + "&handler=DeleteById";
        //options.url = "/Index?id=" + id + "&handler=DeleteById";
        options.url = "/Person/Index?handler=DeleteById&id=" + id;
        options.type = "POST";
        options.headers = {
            RequestVerificationToken:
                $('input:hidden[name="MY-XSRF-TOKEN"]').val()
        };

        options.success = function (data) {
            $("#msg").html("Great Success!");
        };

        options.error = function () {
            $("#msg").html("Error something went wrong with id = " + id + "url: " + options.url);
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }
```

and my Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication20.Data;
using WebApplication20.Models;

namespace WebApplication20.Pages.Person
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WebApplication20.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(WebApplication20.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Models.Person> Person { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Person = await _context.Person.ToListAsync();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostDeleteById(int id)
        {
            var pers = _context.Person.Find(id);
            _context.Remove(pers);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            Person = _context.Person.ToList();
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected this, but it is little vague - If I knew what was wrong I wouldn't be asking this question here :)

Comment: Corrected - thanks for the info

Comment: Your posting data and (i don't know anything about razor pages) your model seems to want a post too, yet your sending the id in the querystring and not the body. Don't format the url yourself, use the jquery `data` property, i.e. `$.ajax(data:{id:id});`. No idea if this will fix it but it looks wrong

Comment: @Liam - thanks for the answer. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: First, you should check the network tab in your browser's development tools (usually accessible by pressing F12). If that shows a 400 response, it is likely because your request verification token is not being passed in the response. The default name for the hidden field is `__RequestVerificationToken`, not `MY-XSRF-TOKEN`. If you have configured it differently, double check that the value is being passed in the request.

Comment: I believe @MikeBrind is correct. Check the name of the hidden field with the verification token. See my similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the problem - I didn't include the button calling the ajax in the form tag