# How to ajax post to a razor page handler?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

The code looks like this

HTML:

```
    <form class="col-sm-6" name="log" >
       <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input name='logText' class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Javascript:

```
        document.forms['log'].onsubmit = () => {

            let formData = new FormData(document.forms['log']);
            fetch('?handler=log', {
                method: 'post',
                body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
            })
                .then(() => {
                    alert('Posted using Fetch');
                });
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

C#:

```
    public void OnPostLog(string logText)
    {

    }
```

The ajax post goes through with a request that looks like this

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44345/?handler=log
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: [::1]:44345
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

However the server returns a 400.  An ajax get works fine.  A full page post to the handler works fine.  Just not an ajax post to a handler.  Is this capability even supported in Razor Pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example AJAX call back to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, there is a __RequestVerificationToken embedded into the form.  and this needs to be supplied during the ajax post.  But for the token to be added to the form, you have to add method="post" the below to the form.

```
        <form class="col-sm-6" name="log" method="post" >
```

Source: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use fetch API, I use the FormData object as the body for the request instead of creating a new URLSearchParams object.

Hope it helps.