# Call server method without page reload with razor page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my .net core razor page project, i would like to call server side methods from a cshtml input without reloading the page. I'm still a newbie with razor pages.

```
.cshtml : 

input type="submit" id="AddCart" asp-page-handler="AddToCart" hidden

Some JS to .click() the input.

.cs :
public async void OnPostAddToCart()
{
//code
}
```

So far i did not find a way to prevent the page reload and still access my server-side methods.

Thanks

EDIT : 
Looking at the link provided by brad, i managed to make it work.

I added @Page "{handler?}" to write the url without the handler (not sure if it matters for ajax),
I set my ajax url to "thePage/theMethod",
I decorated my razor controller class with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
And mentioned the anti forgery token in ajax :

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/mainPage/AddToCart",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    alert("complete")
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
```

Comment: At the moment this is not possible with razor pages alone, you will have to use AJAX.

Comment: Or you can try [Blazor](https://blazor.net), if you are brave enough to use the bleeding-edge experimental frameworks ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page for more info on calling back to a razor page

Answer (score 2):

First ,change the naming of your Handler method like below :

```
 public async void OnPostAddToCartAsync()
    {
        //code
    }
```

Refer to [Handler Methods in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods) for more details on the nameing convention .

Second ,If you want to use ajax in Razor Pages , the URL pattern should be like "/mainPage?handler=AddToCart" .One thing to note down is, Razor Pages are designed to be protected from ([CSRF/XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)) attacks. Hence, Antiforgery token generation and validation are automatically included in Razor Pages. I believe that is the problem here. Your page may have antiforgery token present on the page if you have form tag in your HTML. But you need to pass the same in your Ajax request.

- Add antiforgery token using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, if not
  present.
- Modify your Ajax request to send the same in request header like
  below:

  ```
  <input type="button" id="AddCart"  onclick="clickbtn()" value="Submit"/>
  function clickbtn() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/Test?handler=AddToCart",
          type: 'POST',
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
                  $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
          },
          success: function ()
          {
              alert("success");
          },
          complete: function ()
          {
              alert("complete")
          },
          failure: function ()
          {
              alert("failure");
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- Since the script sends the token in a header called X-XSRF-TOKEN,
  configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-XSRF-TOKEN
  header:

  ```
  services.AddAntiforgery(option => option.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
  ```

  Read this post [Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) to know more about making ajax request with ASP.NET Core razor pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to reload the page you must use `ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest` , (the former being based on the latter).

```
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
  window.click=function()
  {
        $.ajax({  
            url: '[baseUrl/OnPostAddToCart]',  
            data: JSON.stringify(postData), //your data 
            type: 'POST',  
            contentType: 'application/json',  
            dataType: 'json',  

            success: function (result) {  
                alert(result);  //do something if successful
            },  
            complete: function(){  
                 //do something on complete
            },  
            failure: function (err) {                  
                alert(err); // Display error message  
            }  
        });
   }
}
</script>
<input  onclick="click()" type="button"/>
```

**Using** `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
window.click=function()
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "[Your URL]");
xhr.onload=function()
{
  if(xhr.status==200)
    resolve(xhr.response);
  else
    reject("error:"+xhr.status);
}
var data=JSON.stringify({some_data});
xhr.send(data);
}
```

**Controller method**

```
 public class MyController:Controller
 {
    [HttPost]
    [Route("/OnPostAddToCart")]
    public async Task AddToCart(object data)
    {

    }
 }
```

**P.S** For more information on [ajax](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-in-asp-net/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I still can't reach my AddToCart method using this ajax :

$.ajax({
                url: "/mainPage?handler=AddToCart",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function () {
                    alert("success"); 
                },
                complete: function () {
                    alert("complete")
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("failure"); 
                }
            });

I get the "complete" alert.

Comment: You need to specifiy the full `url` in order to reach your server.Find out what the `hostname` and `port` your server is running on and set your `url` attribute to : `http://[hostname]:[port]/OnPostAddToCart`

Comment: The AddToCart method is in the mainPage razor page.

If i use  input id="AddCart" type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddToCart", i reach the method and after the code is executed, my the url is http://localhost:XXXXX/mainPage?handler=AddToCart.

I have tried setting the url attribute to : http://localhost:55318/mainPage?handler=AddToCart; or http://localhost:55318/mainPage/OnPostAddToCart without success.

Comment: If you want to reach a `method` from your `controller` you have to set the url to `[baseurl]/[controller-method]` and decorate your `controller method` with the `Route` attribute like i did in the above example.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adrian. Looking at your Controller method, you can't decorate razor page handler methods with route and HttPost attribute.