# Asp .Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages Ajax Call Post not working

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor-pages

I've done so many ajax in razor pages but i can't figure out why this does not work. It keeps giving me error 400 on dev tools. It does not reach the page handler no matter what.

```
<script>
     $.ajax({
                    url: "/Account/Users/Index?handler=Delete",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        swal("Utilizador Desactivado!", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        swal("Falha na ligação ao servidor. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                    }
                });
</script>
```

page handler

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.IsActivo = false;
            _context.Users.Attach(user).Property( u => u.IsActivo).IsModified = true;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

I tried many url combinations and none work. I don't see what is wrong in here....

**EDIT**

It seems like the problem is the anti forgery token not being validated on razor page.

I wrote Ignore Anti forgery Token on the page model and everything works correctly

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean here? If you debug what's happening?

Comment: it does not reach the page handler, just gives error 400 on dev tools on browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example AJAX call back to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already found out it's the anti forgery token, that is ruining your day.
Now, if you are inside a form, asp.net core will create a hidden input with that token for you. If you are not working with a form on your page, you'll have to call `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, which will add the token for you.
Still, this will not resolve the Bad Request for you. You have to add it to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Users/Index?handler=Delete",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: {
        id: id
    },
});
```

Additionally, add this line to your Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Comment: nevermind, i have 2 ajax functions and i was calling the wrong one hence why it was not working!! It worked right away. Finally I can enojy Ajax on razor pages, thanks alot!

Comment: This has just had be scratching my head for ages. Is it documented anywhere officially?

Comment: Yes @James, although it is somewhat hidden. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mapping of URL use, but as usual it consists of controllerName/actionName/. In your case try to use:

`url: "/Account/OnPostDeleteAsync"`

or

`url: "/Users/OnPostDeleteAsync"`
but if your URL is correct, then try to use [FromForm] attribute

`public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync([FromForm]int? id)`

I hope this will help

Comment: ok i found out the problem, it's the anti forgery token, i wrote [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)] on my page model and i finally hit the page method. I still don't know how do handle tokens in razor pages and i been using controllers instead

Comment: The problem isn't url, it's due to anti forgery token not being validated on razor page