# One-to-Many Relation In Dropdown

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have a one-to-many relation between two entities. 
I would like to allow the user to select one entity from the 'one'-entity via a dropdown in a razor-pages view.

Then a second dropdown in the same view should list all entities that reference the selected entity in the relation.

How would I approach this? Is there a way to update the second dropdown using just C# and cshtml or will I have to use jQuery? If so how?

```cs
public class Entity1
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set;}
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entity2> Entity2s { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set;}
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of other questions about this already (search for 'cascading dropdown list'). Once the page is rendered and client side you will need to use an AJAX callback to the server when the dropdown changes to get an updated list for secondary dropdown. The AJAX call can go back to the same razor page (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page) for an example) or call a separate Web API controller (this [post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/) has an example of that)