# How to use AJAX on ASP.NET MVC RazorPage

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, razor-pages

I am trying to create a cascading DropDownList on ASP.NET RazorPage. After doing some research I found the most common way to do the task is utilizing jQuery in my View. Nearly all demos and examples I found online implement a cascading DropDownList in previous ASP.NET versions, more specifically MVC. I tried translating these examples in the context of how I need them but I am having no luck, most likely due to syntax errors and/or other reasons.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2

I am having trouble specifically implementing the dynamic function call (GetSubCategory) whenever an item is selected in the first DropDownList which is displaying correctly

```
<form asp-controller="my_dropdown" asp-action="CreatePortfolio" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <label for="CategoryName">Category</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("categorylist",
                    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categorylist"], "CategoryId", "CategoryName"), "Select Category", "CategoryName")
                <label for="SubCategoryName">Subcategory</label>

                @section scripts{
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        //Insert default item "Select" in dropdownlist on load
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
                            $("#colorselect").html(items);
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("#CategoryId").on("change", function () {
                                $list = $("#SubCategory");

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: '/CreatePortfolio',
                                    data: { id: $("#CategoryId").val() },
                                    traditional: true,
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        $list.empty();
                                        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                                            $list.append('<option value="' + item["SubCategoryId"] + '"> ' + item["SubCategoryName"] + '</option>');
                                        });
                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        alert("Something went wrong"); // Hide loader icon
                                    },
                                });
                            })
                        })
                    </script>

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code behind the view

```
        public JsonResult GetSubCategory(int CategoryId)
        {
            subcategorylist = _context.GetAllSubCategories(CategoryId);
            //ViewData["subcategorylist"] = subcategorylist;

            return new JsonResult(subcategorylist);
        } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            // ----- Getting Data From Database Using Stored Procedure -----
             categorylist = _context.GetAllCategoires();

            // ----- Assigning categorylist to ViewData["categorylist"] in order to access it in the view -----
            ViewData["categorylist"] = categorylist;
        }


I want the code to correctly display the SubCategories associated to the Category by CategoryId which is a field in both classes/tables
```

Comment: Where is `CreatePortfolio` endpoint written?

Comment: checkout my repo, it provides dynamic selectbox with ajax https://github.com/fajaralmu/organization-management-asp-mvc-webapp/blob/master/OrgWebMvc/Views/Shared/EntityMng.cshtml

Comment: You look to be confusing ASP.NET Core MVC and ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. Your form method points to an MVC controller, but your code behind uses Razor Pages handler methods. Here's a very simple example: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/cascading-dropdowns. Try to replicate that and understand how it works.

Comment: Following the demo @MikeBrind provided, I was able to translate the code in the way I needed and the cascade DropDownList works as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example AJAX call back to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page)