# .NET Core making an AJAX call from a Razor Page to a Controller

Tags: ajax, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET Core 3.1 project using `Razor Pages`. From it I created a simple test where I am able to make a successful Ajax call with the following code:

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public JsonResult OnGetTest()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Ajax Test");
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<div class="text-center">
    <p>Click <a href="#" onclick="ajaxTest()">here</a> for ajax test.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxTest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Index?handler=Test",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

However, I would like to move the Ajax method out of the `Razor Page` and into to a `Controller` so I could call it from from multiple `Razor Pages`. I have created a controller using the following code:

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Ajax Test");
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

But whatever value I use in the `url` for the Ajax call, I get a `404 error`. Does the `Controllers` folder need to be in the `Pages` directory? Or do I need to configure some routing to use a `Controller` with `Razor Pages`?

```
url: "/Ajax/Test" // <-- What goes here?
```

Here is the current directory structure:

[image]

Comment: To enable controller routing in an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages 3.0 app, add `endpoints.MapControllers();` along with `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in the `Configure` method.

Comment: @MikeBrind That didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you including the AnitForgery token somewhere (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416572/27989)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Startup.cs, add this to ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

In Startupcs, also add this to Configure()

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

DisplayController.cs

```
public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hi World");
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<a onclick="ClickMe();">Click Me</a>
<script>
function ClickMe() {
    $.get("/Display/Test", null, function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that the piece I was missing to get mine to work was defining the route in `Startup.cs` : `routes.MapRoute(name: "api", template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");`. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `Route` attribute, like this:

```
[Route("api/Ajax")]
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

It is also best to decorate each individual endpoint with a 'Method' attribute, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return new JsonResult("Ajax Test");
}
```

Furthermore you also need to set the correct configuration in **`Startup.cs`** as shown below, add all the parts that you do not have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    });
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // lots of stuff...

    // I have this after app.UseStaticFiles(), it may also work elsewhere
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    // lots of other stuff...
}
```

And **then** you should be able to call it using the path `/api/Ajax/Test`.

Comment: Please see my update. I added configuration bits, and also made a fix to the Route attribute.