# Razor Pages Javascript Ajax not passing parameters to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor-pages

I have a Javascript function that is meant to end with passing an array back into my c# code

I have got it to reach the c# code, but it never passes a parameter

My Javascript is as follows

```
 var errorsubmits = [];
    var filelists = [];
    var nameselect = document.getElementById("username");
    var nameselected = nameselect.options[nameselect.selectedIndex].text;
    if (nameselected.includes("User"))
        errorsubmits.push("User Name");
    var prioritylevel = document.getElementById("priority");
    var priorityselected = prioritylevel.options[prioritylevel.selectedIndex].text;
    if (priorityselected.includes("Priority"))
        errorsubmits.push("Priority");
    var table = document.getElementById("FileTable");
    var counter = 0;
    var filename = "";
    var images = "";
    var envs = "";
    var printmethod = "";
    var encmethod = "";
    var colour = "";
    var commentsforprint = "";
    var commentsforenclose = "";
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                if (j == 0)
                    filename = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                if (j == 1)
                    images = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                if (j == 2)
                    envs = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                if (j == 3)
                    printmethod = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                if (j == 4)
                    encmethod = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                if (j == 5)
                    colour = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
            }
            else {
                if (j == 1) {
                    if (table.rows[i].cells[j - 1].innerHTML.includes("Print"))
                        commentsforprint = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                    else
                        commentsforenclose = table.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                }

            }
        }
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            if (filename == "")
                errorsubmits.push("Filename (row:" + i + ")");
            if (images == "")
                errorsubmits.push("Images (row:" + i + ")");
            if (envs == "")
                errorsubmits.push("Envs (row:" + i + ")");
            if (printmethod.includes("Method"))
                errorsubmits.push("Print Method (row:" + i + ")");
            if (encmethod.includes("Method"))
                errorsubmits.push("Enc Method (row:" + i + ")");
            if (colour.includes("?"))
                errorsubmits.push("Colour (row:" + i + ")");
            // alert(filename + "\n" + images + "\n" + envs + "\n" + printmethod + "\n" + encmethod + "\n" + colour + "\n" + commentsforprint + "\n" + commentsforenclose);
            filelists.push(nameselected + "\t" + priorityselected + "\t" + document.getElementById('Email').textContent + "\t" + filename + "\t" + images + "\t" + envs + "\t" + printmethod + "\t" + encmethod + "\t" + colour + "\t" + commentsforprint + "\t" + commentsforenclose)
            filename = "";
            images = "";
            envs = "";
            printmethod = "";
            encmethod = "";
            colour = "";
            commentsforprint = "";
            commentsforenclose = "";
            counter = 0;
        }
        else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (errorsubmits.length != 0) {
        alert("Cannot submit!\nThe following lines need filling:\n" + errorsubmits.join("\n"));

    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '?handler=Test',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(filelists)

        });
    }
```

My C# code which is currently functionless as i cant get the data is this

```
public JsonResult OnGetTest(IEnumerable<object>x)
    {
        return new JsonResult("TEST");

    }
```

I have done an alert(JSON.stringify(filelists)) so i know that this works

(If possible i'd like to pass the raw array rather than stringifying it but i was following another SO suggestion)

Comment: Without completely reading through your code, I feel like the culprit is the parameter name 'x'. Can you maybe show how the value "filelists" looks you send to your C# code? If no further config is done, the naming needs to match, so you'd probably need to rename your parameter.

Comment: Hi @Sossenbinder, i tried changing x to filelists but its still null unfortunately

Comment: Are you setting the AntiForgery token see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url `'?handler=Test'` send request like `https://localhost:44389/?handler=Test&filelists=%5B%22nameselected%22%2C%22nameselected1%22%5D`, because it's a `HttpGet` request not a `POST`.

***Edit as per comment***

1 - Function JS :

Push any *string* in the array `filelists`, and change your data to `{ "filelists": JSON.stringify(filelists) }`

```
var filelists = [];
// push strings here
$.ajax({
   url: '?handler=Test',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: { "filelists": JSON.stringify(filelists) }
});
```

2 - In the server side

```
public JsonResult OnGetTest(string filelists)
{
   IEnumerable<string> files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(filelists);

   return new JsonResult("TEST");
}
```

Note that, if you need to send *javascript* objects in the array, you should create classes for *deserializing* data.

Comment: Hi, I dont think this is the solution for my issue. To clarify, i'm trying to call a c# function on a page on a button click, passing some data into it. I can get it to call the c# function via my AJAX but it wont pass data in.

Comment: can you check my update please? the old solution it's also work even for me