# Change target of ajax post in razor page from api in controller to "code-behind" post handler in same razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following ajax post on my index.cshtml razor page which works fine:

```
create: {
            url: "/api/LearningTasks/create",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        },
```

It sends the post to my controller and the code receiving works fine.  It looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/LearningTasks/create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<LearningTask>> CreateLearningTask(LearningTask learningTask)
    {
        _context.LearningTasks.Add(learningTask);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetLearningTask", new { id = learningTask.Id }, learningTask);
    }
```

I would like to change the target of my post so that it goes to the "code-behind" index.cshtml.cs.  The method that I would like to receive it looks like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // This is where I want to have the send the data for the create operation instead of to /api/LearningTasks/create
        _context.LearningTasks.Add(LearningTask);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return null;  
    }
```

I have tried removing the line `url: "/api/LearningTasks/create",` and setting it to `url: "",`  but neither works.  Any help in figuring out how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor Pages are designed to be automatically protected from cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) attacks.

You should send the anti-forgery token in request header to the server using AJAX:

1. Add explicitly using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` ,it will add an input type hidden with name `__RequestVerificationToken`.
2. Send token in request header :

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: '/Index',
       type: 'POST',
       beforeSend: function (xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
               $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
       },   
   })
   .done(function (result) { })
   ```
3. Configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header :

   ```
   services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
   ```

Below article is for your reference :

[Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)