# Calling C# method from JQuery Ajax in .NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this method in Razor Page code behind which I would like to call using JQuery Ajax

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OnPostPopulateMovieDate(int selectedMovieId)
    {
        return new JsonResult("json result");
    }
```

This is my JQuery code to call the method

```
 $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: {selectedMovieId:this.selectedIndex},
            url: "/MovieDateHall/Create?handler=PopulateMovieDate",
            success: function () {
                console.log('ok')
            }
        });
```

I changed my url to `url: "/MovieDateHall/OnPostPopulateMovieDate",` but still no success.

I put a breakpoint in `PopulateMovieDate` method and debug it. But it doesn't reach the breakpoint.

`MovieDateHall` is the sub-folder name under `Pages`.

Comment: From some example I saw, PopulateMovieDate is to call OnPostPopulateMovieDate is Razor Pages. The filename is Create.cshtml / Create.cshtml.cs

Comment: Have you tried using `@Url.Action("//Method", "//Controller")` as your url instead?

Comment: You are trying to submit `{ "selectedMovieId": 123 }` while your controller needs an `int`. Try to build a model class that contains `public int selectedMovieId { get; set; }` as a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In razor page to call ajax method, you should to ensure the following two points :

(you can also refer to  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416572/12884742) )

> 1. Register the Antiforgery-Service
> 2. Add the token to your request
> 3. Add the antiforgery token to your page either by adding a  or by directly using 
>      the @Html.AntiForgeryToken HtmlHelper

According to these, you can change your code as follow:

```html
@page
@model WebApplication1_rzaor_page.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Submit1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    //contentType: "application/json", // remember to remove this line to ensure pass the correct selectedMovieId 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { selectedMovieId: 1 },
                    url: "/MovieDateHall/Create?handler=PopulateMovieDate",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('ok')
                    }
                });
            })

        })
    </script>
} 


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? Did you check the browser console for any javascript error? Please also check the following line exists in your RegisterRoutes method:

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");