# send ajax post request from partial view in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I am trying to send POST Ajax from partial view.
this is my partial view:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/simple-sidebar.css">

<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="links">
        <a href="" onclick='MainTabs()' id="tab1">tab1</a>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function MainTabs() {
        console.log('first');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Main/getddl",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(Session["switch"]);
                console.log('ok');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log('error');
            }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is parent .cs code:

public class MainModel : PageModel
{

```
    public void getddl()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("ddl", "ddl");
    }
```

}

I have 'first' printed in console, but then immediately have an error also error doesn't remain and disappears in a sec.

POST https://localhost:33444/getddl 404

Comment: Be sure to include the Antiforgery token - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem cause this behaviour. I have sidebar and there is a method to active that:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
        document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
    }
```

as this sidebar is the active class, it doesnt know anything about the main page.
I tries to remove active class once one of the item clicked, but no success yet.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#MainTabs').click(function () {
            //e.preventDefault();
            //$('.sidebar a').removeClass('active');
            //$(this).addClass('active');
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#' + id).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + id).addClass("active");
            localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);
            var fullName = $('#texboxFullName').val();
            alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { fullName: fullName },
                url: '@Url.Page("Main", "Demo2")',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result2').html(result);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Any help?