# Ajax call not recognizing URL

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm attempting to make an ajax call within my Razor page. As of right now, my controller method is supposed to return the string "ajax return" and then render that to the appropriate div tag. This is simply a test. I cannot get the ajax call to hit my method in the code behind. Thank you in advance for any input!

ajax:

```js
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("AjaxThing", "Posts")";
        data: "Andrew",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#test").html(response.data);
        }
    });
}

$("#clickMe").on("click", test);
```

cshtml:

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="clickMe" class="btn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

code behind:

```cs
public string AjaxThing() 
{
    return "ajax return";
}
```

Solution layout:

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98TeS.jpg)

Comment: Hmmmm... you aren't calling at all the `test` function...

Comment: Oh dang I left one line out of my post on accident. It's updated now.

Comment: What's written in your developer tools log?

Comment: `url: "@Url.Action("AjaxThing", "Posts")";` - this syntax doesn't look right as you can see with the highlighting. Perhaps it should be `url: @Url.Action("AjaxThing", "Posts");`

Comment: @Xerillio I just tried that and it had no effect.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I've never used the developer tools log so let me figure out how to do that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras inside the chrome dev tools the url reads as: `url: /Status/Posts?action=AjaxThing&amp;controller=Posts`

Comment: And the status of the request? 404 or 500?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console tab?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras 404

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46410716/27989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The reason why it wasnt posting correctly was because I had my controller set up wrong. Instead of inheriting from 'Controller' I updated to 'ControllerBase' which allowed the post to go through. I also updated my ajax call to look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#@formId button').on("click", function (e) {

        var CommentVM = {
            PostId: parseInt($("#@postId").val()),
            Content: $("#@commentId").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PostComment",
            data: JSON.stringify(CommentVM),
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (hxr, status, error) {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpGet]
public string AjaxThing() 
{
    return Json("ajax return",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Please use change the function as shown above, it will work

Comment: Hmm, so it wont actually allow me put that. I get the error `Json doesnt exist in the current context`. Is this because I'm attempting to call this method 'not' from a controller? I have all this placed inside the code behind of the razor page.

Comment: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.3 on your VS project. it iwll resoleve the issue of Json

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {

         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Posts/AjaxThing',
                data: 'Andrew',
                success: function (response) {
                    result = response;
                     $("#test").html(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });          
    }
```

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AjaxThing()
        {
            return Json("ajax return", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```